# Spring Security Concurrent Session Control doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-redis, spring-session

Following the information available here: [Spring Security session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/index.html#spring-security-concurrent-sessions)

Configuring the HttpSecurity object like

```
 http
        .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
            .maximumSessions(2)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()));
```

When auto-wiring FindByIndexNameSessionRepository I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. My store type is Redis.

Answer (score 0):

The exception log is very clear. You need to create and configure the `RedisConnectionFactory` instance in your session configuration class to be able to connect to the redis server.